# Play Framework 2.0 - where is jsAction?

Tags: playframework-2.0

Does Play Framework 2.0 have any built-in equivalent to 1.2.x's [jsAction](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/ajax)?

If not, how can I create such a tag?

Update:
Thanks to Julien Richard-Foy who got me on the right track, I was able to use javascriptRouter. However, Play 2.0 doesn't provide any examples on how to use it in their manuals, [so I made an example on how it is used in Java](http://franzgranlund.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/play-framework-2-0-javascriptrouter-in-java/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is a [`play.api.Routes`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.Routes$) object providing a way to generate a JavaScript reverse router. There also is a template tag, [`helper.javascriptRouter`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.javascriptRouter$), which can be used directly in the templates.

Answer (score 3):

For scala:

```
def javascriptRoutes() = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(
      Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
        // Routes
        controllers.routes.javascript.Application.xxx,
        controllers.routes.javascript.Application.yyy
      )
    ).as(JAVASCRIPT)
  }
```

and in your template

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Application.javascriptRoutes"></script>
```

routes usage is explained at @Franz his blog: http://franzgranlund.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/play-framework-2-0-javascriptrouter-in-java/

Comment: +1 for the fun I had finding out that the blog post you referenced comes from the OP. Infinite recursion here :)